# How to draw Bezier-Curve C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gdi+, bezier

I need to draw an bezier curve. But the problem is my code bring this output:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

How can i "delete" the rest of the lines. I don't know how tho draw the control polygon only on his finest Level of polyline.

```
    private void pb_Bezier_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point P1 = new Point(10, 300);
        Point P2 = new Point(180, 50);
        Point P3 = new Point(320, 300);

        ZeichneBezier(6, P1, P2, P3, e);
    }

    private void ZeichneBezier(int n, Point P1, Point P2, Point P3, PaintEventArgs pva)
    {
        Graphics g = pva.Graphics;
        Pen kpStift = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Pen bkStift = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

        for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                g.DrawLine(bkStift, P1, P2);
                g.DrawLine(bkStift, P2, P3);
            }
            else
            {
                Point P12 = new Point((P1.X + P2.X)/2,(P1.Y + P2.Y)/2);
                Point P23 = new Point((P2.X + P3.X)/2,(P2.Y + P3.Y)/2);
                Point P123 = new Point((P12.X + P23.X)/2,(P12.Y + P23.Y)/2);

                ZeichneBezier(n-1, P1, P12, P123, pva);
                ZeichneBezier(n-1, P123, P23, P3, pva);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't know if that is a homework task or not, but note that `Graphics` also has specific methods for drawing beziers, so you could save yourself the hassle of approximating a bezier curve with line segments...

Comment: Yes you are right @elgonzo, this is homework :D I know there are these methods to draw a bezier curve, but we need to it like this :(

Comment: Since it's a homework, lets throw back the question to you :-) How do (or would) you determine when you are at the finest level of the polyline?

Comment: i thought it would be a curve with 3 Points is that right? start, control, end. Or do I have to draw only the midpoints of the lines? so Points? sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see how this is related to the question i asked. if you want your program to draw the polyline only on its finest level, you need to have an answer to the question: How does (or how could) my program determine whether it is at that finest level and should draw or whether it is not yet at the finest level and should not yet draw?

Comment: Sorry. Here is the the task that i have: "A Bézier curve of degree 2 is described by specifying three points P1, P2, P3. The polyline connecting the points is called "control polygon". The curve runs inside its control polygon. There is a recursive algorithm to draw the curve. This divides the curve and creates new points: the control polygons of the subdivided curve pieces. The control polygons approach the curve. At the finest level, the control polygon is drawn as a polyline."

Comment: "The recursive method DrawBezier (n, P1, P2, P3) can be formulated as follows:  If n == nMax: draw the lines P1, P2 and P2, P3first: 1.Calculate three new pointsP12 = 0.5 * (P1 + P2) P23 = 0.5 * (P2 + P3) P123 = 0.5 * (P12 + P23) 2. recursively call the n -1 method for points P1, P12, P123, and P123, P23, P3, respectively."

Comment: No, i understand. I can glean from your code in the question that the purpose of the homework is part of teaching you about geometry, and more importantly recursion. I asked you two times the same question, but you do not seem wanting to follow through. I am all in in helping you understanding the problem and finding a solution, but i am not going to do your homework for you. It will just set you up for failure down the line, as further classes and course work will rely on you understanding and using recursion.

Comment: This chap explains this more eloquently than i could here: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: So, i try again: How do (or would) you in your program determine when you are at the finest level of the polyline?

Comment: no I do not want you to do me my homework. I'm sorry if I formulated my question wrong. I just do not know. I have no one to ask. i do my computer science studies only beside work, it is quite exhausting to work 45 hours a week and to study at the same time. I want to understand where my mistake lies and how to get it. but thanks anyway for your help, I will delete the post the next half hour again.

Comment: @elgonzo i dont know! i dont know, what the finest level of the polyline is! that is my question. that is my problem, i never had bezier curves in my life! its a c# curse and not a math curse.

Comment: Okay, lets try a different approach: What are the arguments `n`,`P1`,`P2`,`P3` in your *ZeichneBezier* method, what are they used for, do you understand their purpose? (fyi: The PaintEventArgs argument is irrelevant for the problem at hand.)

Comment: P1, P2, P3 are the Points are the Points for the Controlpolygon. n is number of passes for the algorithm. foreach pass of the algorithm there are 3 new points. i dont know how to explain in english. then i draw 2 lines foreach half of the "triangle". i think the finest level of the polyline are the two midpoints of these 2 new lines am i right? so the inly thing what i need to do is, do draw the midpoints of the 2 new lines? i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Okay. That's good. Now lets try getting you closer to understand your problem: What i can take from your question (and images) is that the problem is your program is drawing too many lines that should not be there. So it comes down to the question: When does your program draw lines (in which situation, under which conditions)? The question here is not about what you think the program should do, but rather: Look at your code (follow its flow) and identify the conditions that cause a line to be drawn (irregardless of whether this line is correct or not).

Comment: the lines are drawn at the beginning of the loop. that means at the first run of the loop 3 times. At the beginning if n = 6 and then in the recursive call of the method again 2 times, because then again 2 times n = 6 applies

Comment: Okay, yes. While this draws the approximate bezier, it also obviously draws unwanted lines that are not part of the approx. bezier. What do you think these unwanted lines are, where do their drawing coordinates/points come from?

Comment: I'll have to go. Keep working on your problem. If you work on understanding your program and its flow, you'll sooner or later will understand the nature of the beast. Then you should be able to revisit the description of the task/homework and see how your current program differs from the task description and how to make it right :)

Comment: this are the 2 g.DrawLine in the if clausal.

Comment: okay thank you very much @elgonzo. I think you helped me a lot. I think i got the issue an can figure out how i need to do it. Thank you! :)

Comment: It seems you did not understand my last question. My question was not "How does your program draw a line on the screen?" My question was very different ;-) Anyway, i'll have to leave now :)

Comment: ah sorry i read it wrong. the coordinates come frome the recursive call and i calculate then in the else clausal

Comment: so my problem is i draw all the lines, but at least i need 3 points to make a polygon and that i dont draw it in the for loop

Comment: Talking about homework and Bezier-Curves, [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) is an interesting read, including animations and a link to source code (top right corner).

Comment: I am voting to close the question because I don't know what the problem at hand is. Is it how to draw with different colors, how to code this homework assignment or how to draw a Bezier curve in general? It seems the answer needs to be specific to your case, but not too specific as to not give away the answer to a homework problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this one...

```
    private void pb_Bezier_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point P1 = new Point(10, 300);
        Point P2 = new Point(180, 50);
        Point P3 = new Point(320, 300);

        ZeichneBezier(6, P1, P2, P3, e, true);
    }

    private void ZeichneBezier(int n, Point P1, Point P2, Point P3, PaintEventArgs pva, bool initial)
    {
        Graphics g = pva.Graphics;
        Pen bkStift = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Pen kpStift = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        if(initial)
        {
            g.DrawLine(kpStift, P1, P2);
            g.DrawLine(kpStift, P2, P3);
        }

        if (n > 0)
        {
            Point P12 = new Point((P1.X + P2.X) / 2, (P1.Y + P2.Y) / 2);
            Point P23 = new Point((P2.X + P3.X) / 2, (P2.Y + P3.Y) / 2);
            Point P123 = new Point((P12.X + P23.X) / 2, (P12.Y + P23.Y) / 2);

            ZeichneBezier(n - 1, P1, P12, P123, pva, false);
            ZeichneBezier(n - 1, P123, P23, P3, pva, false);
        }
        else
        {
            g.DrawLine(bkStift, P1, P2);
            g.DrawLine(bkStift, P2, P3);
        }
    }
```

Your for loop seems to be not necessary and decreases your performance.

I've added a parameter "bool initial" to decide when to draw the black lines.

Only first call of ZeichneBezier in pb_Bezier_Paint event handler should draw the lines.